# 'config.assets.compile = false' statement making one of my js plugins images unaccessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In production environment of my Rails application, I have `config.assets.compile = false`, and because of this statement, One of my JS plug-in images are not accessible.

If I make `config.assets.compile = true` then can access those images of JS plugin.

I am wondering if there is a way to make `config.assets.compile = true` for some specific assets in my Rails app. Or Could someone suggest any other solution for my problem.

BTW I am having problem with **highslide js**(http://highslide.com/) plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just precompile that asset file?

Comment: The assets are precompiled successfully,I just can't access images of highslide js after compilation even if the images paths are correct.

Comment: Are all images specified there inside `'/assets/images'` folder?

Comment: Yes in '/assets/images', Also found the compiled images in 'public/assets/'.

Comment: Can you just show how you are referencing images? Or else just check `http://localhost:3000/assets/your_image_name_with_extension`, it should display the image in your browser. Otherwise you can assume that it is not properly added to assets.

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:3000/assets/'path_of_my_images' already, I don't see expected image rather I see 404 page not found issue. Seems highslide doesn't support asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't resolve this issue by using asset pipeline.

I have to put highslide js images in public folder for making highslide js plugin features work.

Thanks!